# How to center/align Google Maps in a div with a variable width

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've got a Google Maps loaded in a div that is 100% the width of the page (via API).
The overlay is positioned in the center and the map should be positioned like this to.
The problem is the map is now aligned to the left.

I could move the center with LatLng corresponding to the width of the page, but this seems like a lot of work for a simple task. I've been looking through the API-reference but couldn't find a solution.

Is there any way in the Maps API (v3) to position/align the map in/to the center ?

**Edit:**

When you resize the browserwindow in this example:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_fullscreen1.htm

The map is aligned to the topleft of the window.

What I want is the center of the map staying in the center of the window when resizing it.

So the map would move 100px to the right if the window got 200px wider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by having two `div`, one inside the other, you can center the inner one even using percentages.
and attach an event handler to re-center the map on each `resize` event.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="map_go" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var currCenter = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(currCenter);
})
```

**CSS**

```
#outerdiv {width: 90%; height: 90%; position:fixed; text-align:center}
#map_go {width: 70%; height: 100%; margin:0px auto; display:inline-block}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/eXCFw/

*tested with firefox 15*

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks! I didn't need the outer div though, is this for cross-browser improvements? This fiddle is enough for me I guess: http://jsfiddle.net/eXCFw/3/

Answer (score 6):

I tried this and it worked fine for me

```
#map-canvas { height: 70%; width :50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

Comment: Even in-line: margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm

It describes the issues with percentage sized divs and maps (which need to know the rendered size of the map). It is from Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial, but the concept applies to v3 as well.

Comment: It's not really what I meant, but I can use it as a good example for my problem. When you resize the browserwindow in that example (http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_fullscreen1.htm) the map is aligned to the topleft of the window. What I want is the center of the map staying in the center of the window when resizing it. So the map would move 100px right if the window got 200px wider.

Comment: @Tim Try adding `padding` or changing `width` value

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you would need 2 DIVs to achieve that.

One DIV is enough:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var currCenter = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(currCenter);
});
```

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/RGUnd/2/